# I am getting an error when I try to run an app that will ask questions

Tags: ios, swift, nsexception

I am trying to make an app that will ask questions and you have to answer True or False. This is part of an online course I am taking. I started with the challenge of displaying on the screen " four + two is equal to 6" and displaying it. Here is the code I wrote in order to display that.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var optionBar: UIProgressView!
    @IBOutlet weak var trueButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var falseButton: UIButton!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        questionLabel.text = "Four + two is equal to 6"
    }



    @IBAction func answerButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
}
```

When I try to run the simulator, I get the error:

> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

and it brings me to my appDelegate screen and shows the error:

> Exception: "[<Quizzler_iOS13.ViewController 0x7f9b90608020> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key question.

on line 3. Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```

Do any of you guys know how to fix this?